# TFS 2012 Branching- Copy Dev as Main

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

I currently have a solution in TFS with only a Dev Folder:

```
/Dev
```

I would like to implement a branching strategy for this solution:

```
/Dev
/Main
```

I understand I can use the Convert to Branch feature, however how can I establish a relationship between the new parent (Main) branch and the existing child (Dev) branch?

I do not want to rename Dev to Main because I want to preserve the existing check-in history in the dev branch.  Is there another way I can do this to establish the existing Dev branch as child and the new Main branch as parent, without having to rename Dev?

Comment: I strongly recommend you read and understand the [Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Branching and Merging Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @JohnSaunders... I've read it, multiple times.  Is there something in my question that makes it seem like I'm missing something fundamental?  The problem I'm dealing with right now is I have source code that uses no branching strategy, and I would like to get it to a state where it does.

Comment: Yes. You're only trying to create two branches; three is pretty much the minimum; and if you had read it, I wonder why you created the structure you did.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I will also be creating a release branch, but once the Main branch is set-up properly doing so will be trivial (I didn't mention it as I thought it could only over-complicate the question). With that mentioned, this seems to me to look identical to the Basic Branch Plan described in the guide.

Comment: Are you sure you lose the history if you rename /Dev to /Main?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I won't lose the history, but it will reside in Main instead of Dev (the only history in Dev would then be the branch from main).  Not the end of the world but something I would like to avoid if there is a way to.

Comment: But that history _belongs_ in Main. That's where you did the work. Once  you  branch from Main to Dev, you will do all _subsequent_ work in Dev.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If main doesn't exist yet then just take a branch from dev and call it Main. Once you've done this then you can reparent the branch so that dev is a child of main.

To do this select Dev in source control explorer and right click, then select "Branching and merging". Finally select "reparent" and use the UI to change the relationship with main.

If Main does exist then you will need to perform a [baseless merge](http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2012/08/baseless-merge-vs-2012-ui/) to establish the branch relationship

Comment: Before you can reparent Dev branch, first you will need to reparent Main to "no parent".